# Como definir escopo de CSS em wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

Mesmo utilizando a função `body_class()` que retorna o nome da pagina ou o `id` da mesma ao aplicar uma determinada regra em `css` alguns elementos em outras paginas sofrem mudanças, por exemplo:

Home:

```
<body <?= body_class(); ?>> <!-- retorna uma string "home" -->
    <div class="hero">
        <h1 class="title">Titulo</h1>
    </div>
...
```

Pagina de contato:

```
<body <?= body_class(); ?>> <!-- retorna uma string "page-id-5" -->
    <div class="hero">
        <h1 class="title">Titulo</h1>
    </div>
...
```

Ao utilizar o `css` eu tento sempre utilizar a primeira classe que esta em `body`, ou seja:

```
.page-id-5 .hero .hero-body .title {
    color: white;
}
```

Porém mesmo assim essa regra esta sendo aplicada na pagina `home`, qual é a melhor maneira de separar os `css's` entre paginas no `wordpress`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Com esses dados que você postou não vai dar pra reproduzir o problema. Deve ser algo específico do seu código. Tente reproduzir num exemplo simples e atualize a pergunta.

Comment: porque você acha que não pra pra reproduzir? este é exatamente o problema que estou enfrentando, o `title` que esta dentro da "arvore" de `.page-id-5` esta se aplicando em lugares onde não estao na hierarquia do css (iniciando com `.page-id-5`)

Comment: Porque se não tem uma classe `page-id-5` acima de `.hero .title` não tem como o CSS aplicar o seletor `.page-id-5 .hero .title`.

Comment: @bfavaretto coloquei um print para você ver.

Comment: Olhe o seletor da imagem que você postou, é diferente do que você descreveu na pergunta.

Comment: já adicionei o `hero-body` na pergunta.

Comment: Não é essa a diferença, no da imagem tem uma vírgula que não tem na pergunta. Ela faz toda a diferença, isola o `.title`.

Comment: entendi, eu achei que ao utilizar a virgula dentro dos seletores que selecionaria o `hero-body` e o `title` na mesma ordem dos seletores pai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema que está acontecendo conforme o @bfavaretto já informou é que na sua folha de estilo  `contato.css` na linha 7 está assim:

```
.page-id-5 .hero .hero-body, .title {
    color: white;
}
```

### O correto seria assim:

Sem a vírgula depois de `.hero-body`

```
.page-id-5 .hero .hero-body .title {
    color: white;
}
```

### UPDATE

Caso queira deixar todo o texto dentro de hero-body com a cor branca incluindo os títulos o `css` correto deve ser da seguinte forma:

```
.page-id-5 .hero .hero-body, .page-id-5 .hero .hero-body .title {
    color: white;
}
```

Desta forma você está definindo o css para aplicar a cor branca em todo os texto que estiver dentro de `hero-body` e também em todos os texto que tem a classe `title`.

A classe `title` por padrão receberia a cor branca por herança de `hero-body`. Mas provavelmente seu tema tem a classe `title` atribuindo outra cor a ela, então com este css `.page-id-5 .hero .hero-body .title` você defini que toda classe `title` que estiver dentro da classe `hero-body` irá receber a cor branca.

A vírgula é usada para iniciar outra classe `css` que irá ter o estilo que você vai definir em comum.

Comment: O que eu pretendo é deixar todo o texto dentro de `hero-body` com a cor branca incluindo os titulos, quando utilizo a virgula ao que eu entendo deveria funciona com os seletores utilizados anterioemente para abranger todo o `hero-body` e o titulo e não que o titulo é "excluido"

Comment: @Rafael Acioly eu acabei de atualizar minha resposta te dando uma melhor explicação. Veja por favor.